# White Space from top

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have added a Storyboard to my project.

These are settings of my project, I have attached for reference.
[image]

I have googled and search on StackOverflow community as well, but I am unable to remove the white space before title.Please refer below screen.
[image]

Thanks you for the guidance

**Edit 1**

How I want
[image]

How do I am getting after following [J.Hunter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077222/1887603)
[image]

**Edit 2**

[image]

Comment: I think your top is 20 pixels from navigation bar.

Comment: Set Top bar none and check.

Comment: That has neither helped

Comment: Why not use navigation controller instead of navigation bar

Comment: I created a project and try to duplicate your issue via add navigation bar to a view controller in storyboard. All the things seems ok. so show more detail about your auto layout setting of `Title`

Comment: Embed your controller to navigation controller and then set constraint for label.

Comment: @J.Hunter I have added a new storyboard to my project, that where I am facing the problem. Its working perfectly with the Main.storyboard

Comment: I will post my storyboard setting and snapshot as an answer. I want to know what kind of constraints you had added to the `Title`

Comment: @title is navigation bar which I have dragged from object library

Comment: It's not a iOS style, dragging a navigation bar into view controller instead of embed in a navigation controller. On the other hand, you still don't show me your constraints added to `Title`, which will decided how your ui shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a project and try to duplicate your issue via add navigation bar to a view controller in storyboard. 

You may note that I add leading, trailing and top constraints to `Title`. I want to know what kind of constraints you had added to your `Title`.
**Constraints**
[image]

Edit: implement all this in a new storyboard
[image]

**Snapshot**
[image]

Comment: Please add a new stroyboard to your project and try the same

Comment: @onkar You can see there are many view controller scene in my screenshot. So what's mean your said, add a new storyboard? a new `stroyboard file`?

Comment: @onkar see my update. Is there any difference between two way?

Comment: glad, but I want onkar below 9:36 pm not where it is right now.

Comment: @onkar In my screenshot, I show the size inspector on Xcode's right panel. You can see three constraints for navigation bar. Why you not show yours?

Comment: @onkar It looks like your view controller not embed in a navigation controller. Your storyboard looks different from mine. Why there is a navigation bar(not title) in your snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your viewDidLoad method,

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

or Go to main storyboard. Select view controller. Look at the propertied section . You will notice something lik "Adjust Scroll view Insects" in attribute inspector. if you do not want top spacing.then uncheck "Under Top Bars". if you don not want bottom spacing.then uncheck "Under Bottom Bars".